# Adding Jetty session by IP address

Tags: java, jetty, spark-framework

I'm using spark framework WebSockets for building P2P Http Backend and all I want to know is how to create session manually by entering IP address of peer?

Comment: Are you talking `javax.websocket.Session`? or `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession`?

Comment: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session